# Suppressing iTunes Licensing Agreement for Roaming Profiles

Tags: windows-7, itunes

This application is stored locally from our company image we are testing, but our users are using roaming profiles and each time they log in to a different computer or the main computer they work on iTunes keeps asking them to accept the licensing agreement. Is there anyway to keep this agreement from coming up since they are not storing this information in their profile or on the computer locally?

All the computers are on Windows 7 and we run a Server 2008 R2 Domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken Apple uses a per-computer licensing model not a per user model, thus every computer a person logs into with their remote profile is a completely different computer according to Apple and their licensing model.  This becomes important as Apple only allows you to "allow" a specified number of computers, not users, to access your DRMd content.

If you're hell bent on getting around the EULA screen you may be able to have a script as part of your remote profile which places the appropriate flag/file on the local system.  Though that may have some legal ramifications as you are essentially bypassing a EULA agreement for a program which seems to be essentially licensed per computer not per user or user profile